# Creating a Square Flexbox Based on the Smallest Width / Height of Parent DOM Using Bootstrap (With React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Is there an *elegant* way to create a square card / div using bootstrap flexboxes with minimal custom css and/or using built-in bootstrap properties if at all possible?

My goal is to get this responsive square in the middle of this card based on the minimum width or height of the doms parent with some margin

so basically the square would be of size NxN where

```
N = Math.min(parentWidth, parentHeight) - (marginSize * 2);
```

[image]

This is what I have

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">url.com</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="card m-5 h-100 flex-grow-1 rounded-0">
        <div class="card small-cards m-5 h-100 flex-grow-1 rounded-0 border-0">I WANT THIS TO BE SQUARE :)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I was able to come up with that met my needs/wants in case this question picks up In the search results:

[image]

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-nNK9n28pDUDDgIiIqZ/MiyO3F4/9vsMtReZK39klb/MtkZI3/LtjSjlmyVPS3KdN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>url.com</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">url.com</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center">
        <div class="card small-card h-100 flex-grow-1 rounded-0 align-self-center" style="max-width: 85vmin; min-width: 85vmin; min-height: 85vmin; max-height: 85vmin;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```